# If $v \in W^{1,\infty}\left([0,T];X\right)$ and $\|u\|_V\leq \|v\|_X$, do we have $u\in W^{1,\infty}\left([0,T];V\right)$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $V, X$ be two Banach spaces, and $v:[0,T]\rightarrow X ,\  u:[0,T]\rightarrow V .$

if $v \in W^{1,\infty}\left([0,T];X\right)$ and we have this relation   $$\|u\|_V\leq \|v\|_X,$$

Is there a result which says that$$u\in W^{1,\infty}\left([0,T];V\right)?$$

Comment: This isn't even true if $X=V=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: expanding the above comment, set, $u=\mathbf 1_{[0,T/2]}$ and $v$ any smooth function on $[0,T]$ with $|u|\le |v|$.